# React Native Location evaluating 'nativeModule.__expo_module_name__'

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, location

I have installed expo Location:

```
npx expo install expo-location
```

And whenever I try to use it in my application get an Error

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
console.log(Location) //Leads to an Error when I try to call it
```

ERROR:

```
Android Bundling complete 3254ms
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nativeModule.__expo_module_name__')
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

dependencies in Package.Json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    **"expo": "~47.0.9",**
    "expo-file-system": "~15.1.1",
    **"expo-location": "~15.0.1",**
    "expo-updates": "^0.15.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this Error by doing a re-build using eas

```
eas build --profile development --platform android
```

Comment: I had the same issue with Expo Video `npx expo install expo-av` and rebuilding worked too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the error occurs because in the package.json file, the requested module is only listed under devDependencies instead of dependencies. I copied it to dependencies and the issue was resolved.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Otzp.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.